# Simple script running on server and app communicating with it

Tags: python, wordpress, ubuntu, server, vps

new to web development and i need some help to figure out the basics.I have a website right now,which is working fine,on a VPS with Ubuntu 16.04 and Apache.Say i would like a converter in my site or in a mobile application and have a python script in my server doing all the work.How can i send the python program the request and how can the page/application receive the data back(like download link,or info like JSON).

A simple information would suffice,i don't need a thorough explanation,mostly names like protocols,etc.. maybe some sample code for Hello World.

I should add that my website runs with Wordpress and i am not looking to change that yet.I want to create a web app within wordpress,with the app written in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using something like AWS Lambda. Lambda is an AWS product that will allow you to host your function online and you can just call it with HTTP requests and GET a response. More at aws.amazon.com/lambda

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like Django or Flask. Both are used for building back end of web apps.